# How to display the folder created in external storage/Internal Storage, in the App screen

Tags: android

I'm new to android and trying to create simple apps. Please bear with me if my question is simple. I have written the below code to create a folder in the external storage on a button click in menu bar.

```
String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString() +  "/NewFolder";    
System.out.println("Path  : " + Path);    
File FPath = new File(Path);    
if (!FPath.exists()) {   
    if (!FPath.mkdir()) {   
        System.out.println("***Problem creating Image folder " + Path);  
    }  
}
```

And given write permission in the manifest on external storage.

The folder is getting created successfully in the external storage.

What i want is the code to display this new folder in my app screen i.e when i click on the button, i want the new folder created to be displayed in the application screen. Please help me with this.